# Did AOC ever make this statement about daylight savings time and global warming?

Tags: politics, quotes

[image: AOC meme on Daylight Savings]

> If we change our times with the sole intent of increasing the amount of daylight we receive, that's an extra hour of sunshine that will warm the planet. That's one extra hour per day of extra heat warming our already unstable planet. We need to repeal Daylight Savings Time as a primary measure to decrease the rate of climate change. Fewer hours of sunshine equal less heat hitting Earth's surface. We're running out of time! Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez

You can see [this meme shared here by "Joseph Rudy Rullo" the 2017 Republican candidate for Governor of New Jersey](https://www.facebook.com/Rullo2017/photos/a.272117269490295/2282333098468692/?type=3&theater)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, this is a replay of the similar meme about AOC and Daylight Savings Time from March which started as satire from [NPC Daily](https://web.archive.org/web/20190325190038/https://npcdaily.com/2649/aoc-opposes-daylight-savings-time-because-the-extra-hour-of-sunlight-drastically-speeds-up-climate-change/)

- [Daylight Saving Time Spoof Story Not Real](https://www.factcheck.org/2019/03/daylight-saving-time-spoof-story-not-real/)